# PHP Library for Amazon S3 with local fallback

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-s3

Is there a library out there for PHP to access Amazon S3 that will let me use the exact same code to either read/write S3 buckets or to do the same with local files?

I would like to use S3 but I need a way to run my application locally for testing.

If there is not a library that directly supports switching to a local filesystem, is there one that is written in a good OOP manner so that I could use the same interface to make a local filesystem version of it?

I'm using Symfony2 so if there are bundles for this that would be a plus but I can always make it a bundle myself.

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to make a bundle now to do this.  I just need the operations "create", "exists", and "delete" so I made an interface to handle that.  Then I have a "local" implementation and an "S3" implementation.

What's a clean, Symfony2 method of allowing another class to access some service by ID and get either the `LocalStorage` or the `S3Storage` class depending on a config parameter?  I thought about using a "class" parameter, but my S3 service has a dependency on the underlying AmazonS3 class (using the AWS bundle).

Comment: `but I can always make it a bundle myself.` --- if you do - share it on github ;-)

Comment: So no one has done this? I'm really curious how people use S3 with local development and testing...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for the library called [Gaufrette](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette). There is also [KnpGaufretteBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle) available for Symfony2. It has all you need.

Comment: Well thanks for that! I wish I had found it sooner.  I had just started implementing my own (same concept, but at a much simpler scale to meet my needs).  I'm definitely going to use this since I haven't written tests for my implementation and I trust the Knp code to be well tested.

Comment: Good luck. It is a good library (I use it for 2 prod sites myself).